# What is the difference copy command - windows

Tags: windows, copy, information-hiding

can anybody explain the difference between these 2 commands? i know in general what they do but do not understand what the effects would be given that (1) and (2) have the first parameters mirrored.

(1) copy /b imagefile.jpg + archive.rar newimagefile.jpg

(2)copy /b archive.rar + imagefile.jpg newimagefile.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator for the copy command means "file concatenation".  That is:

`copy A+B C`

Means copy the contents of `A` **followed by** the contents of `B` to a new file called `C`.

In the first example, the resulting file, `newimagefile.jpg` is composed of the following structure:

```
-----------------------------
| CONTENTS OF IMAGEFILE.JPG |
-----------------------------
| CONTENTS OF ARCHIVE.RAR   |
-----------------------------
```

In the second example you provided, the newimagefile.jpg is composed differently.

```
-----------------------------
| CONTENTS OF ARCHIVE.RAR   |
-----------------------------
| CONTENTS OF IMAGEFILE.JPG |
-----------------------------
```